# How to delete custom post type from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have an empty post type that I registered in past.
This post type 'workshop' has no posts and the register function is not there anymore.

I tried to unregister the post type, because its still showing up in the WordPress menue.

I had no sucess with: `unregister_post_type`.

What is the proper way to delete from WordPress and from MySQL as well?
Thank you.

Comment: If there are no posts then you don't need to remove anything from the db. You have to find out if you do unregister_post_type actually after the post type is registered. Otherwise it won't work ofcourse.